# ld can't find c file

Tags: c, assembly, linker, ld

I have a assembly file and a c file compiled to .o files (start.o and main.o) and is trying to link them with ld. I'm using this command:

```
ld -T link.ld -o kernel.bin start.o main.o
```

where link.ld is a linker script, but when I run it, i get this error:

```
start.o:start.o:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `_main'
```

in the assembly file, I call the c file with this function:

```
stublet:
extern _main
call _main

jmp $
```

Anybody can see what's wrong?

Comment: What's the linker script for?

Comment: @pjc50 This code looks to be the same im working on now.  A tutorial on basic kernel development. 
http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/Docs/creatingmain.htm

For the relevant page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some compilers (like GCC for Linux) don't add `_` by default to C library exports. Try `nm main.o` to see the actual reference name. It might be `main` rather than `_main`.

Answer (score 0):

Some linkers are sensitive to the order that object files or libraries appear on the command line - try swapping the order of your two object files.

I should also point out that the C standard makes no guarantee that main() is a function - in fact, C programs are explicitly forbidden to call main.